# Defining spatial reference using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I want to define with ArcGis Pro the right spatial reference for a layer, which has no coordinate system asigned, but coordinates - 300.040,40940 Top and 424.407,907900 Right.
I am not really certain, how can I recognise with the given coordinates the real projection or CS.

Do you have any idea, or does my question make sense?

Comment: It looks like a local datum, too big to be geographic, too small to be projected. You will need to find out what the datum and projection are from the place you got the data from... your only other choice is to use the spatial adjustment toolbar to warp to known to be accurate data in the same area.

Comment: But you probably know at least country location od this layer?

Comment: what are the four coordinates ? Do you know where it should be ?

Comment: Hi @TomazicM yes, the country is Austria and the layer should be on the border between Germany and Austria near by Salzburg (Saalach).

Comment: Hi @radouxju the four other coordinates are: Top 300.040,409400 Bottom: 298.970,669300 Left: 424.407,188200 Right: 425.163,907900

Comment: @MichaelStimson: thank you very much for the hint, unfortunately I cannot find the tool in ArcGIS Pro. I am curently studying GIS (MSc) and this is one the tasks

Comment: It looks like it's not there, see GeoNet: https://community.esri.com/ideas/15484-add-spatial-adjustment-toolbar-to-arcgis-pro but you could use something like https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/editing/rubbersheet-features.htm to achieve the same results. Before attempting to adjust the data yourself exhaustively try to find out what the real (local) coordinate system information is.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thank you very much Michael for your help and hints. I managed the task, it was a MGI Austria GK M31 coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to https://epsg.io/, select CRS EPSG:3416 and input top left coordinates, this is what you get:

[image] 
If this CRS is not the right one, you can try also some other CRSs that cover Austria, just search for Austria on https://epsg.io/